# Is there any way to save a textfile in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a couple of textfiles that have to be automatically printed into a text container in chrome via selenium.
How do I save a textfile in a variable tho..?

I have looked through the web and this is what I found and tried:

Method #1

```
file1 = open(r'C:\Users\Arjan\Desktop\PythonProjekt\Jobbeschreibungen\UHD' , 'r')
print file1.readline()
```

Method #2

```
File_object = ""
print(File_object.read(r'C:\Users\Arjan\Desktop\PythonProjekt\Jobbeschreibungen\UHD'))
```

Using the first method up above I got this error message:

```
Syntax Error: invalid syntax: <string>, line 2, pos 11
```

Using the second method I got this one:

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

What I want to do is just paste the text within the textfile into a text container on a website via selenium.

Comment: You want text file content in a variable right ? Why not just do `content = file1.readlines()`

Comment: would I put the path of the file instead of file1?

Comment: no the file object you created, `file1 = open(r'C:\Users\Arjan\Desktop\PythonProjekt\Jobbeschreibungen\UHD' , 'r')
` this to be exact

Comment: I don't get an error message anymore but when I try to `print(content)` '[]' gets printed

Comment: The path you have passed is not to a text file, change that to the path of a text file

Comment: aah now it works but... any idea how I can combine that with selenium's `send_keys` function?

Comment: You can send strings as it is, i assume

Comment: Ah thanks alot everything works as it should now. Do you have any idea if I can only read .txt documents or word-documents aswell? Since the formatting is somewhat important and it gets lost when I read it from .txt file

Answer (score 0):

Use the `read()` method of a file to read the entire file and assign it to a variable.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Arjan\Desktop\PythonProjekt\Jobbeschreibungen\UHD' , 'r') as file1:
    variable = file1.read()
```

Comment: When I try `print(variable)` it doesn't output anything tho

Answer (score 0):

`read()` method works here.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Arjan\Desktop\PythonProjekt\Jobbeschreibungen\UHD', 'r') as f:
    var = f.read()
    print(var)
```

use your file location carefully and make sure your file contains something if it does not print anything.

Thank you